# Clicking Web Links in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

My question is simple- Using Selenium, how do you keep on clicking links when each hyper link opens up in a new page or new window or opens in the same web page.

For example I have following links on a webpage:
Log in
Sign up
Forgot Password?
Signup with us
follow this link
Home
Terms
Privacy Policy

Here is the small snippet of code that I have written to click these mentioned links on webpage:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        //clicking all links
        for (WebElement el : elements){
            System.out.println("Link getting clicked"  + el.getText());
            el.click();
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
```

As you can see I am trying to get links and trying to click them one by one. However, I am getting an error after the first click itself. Console says:  "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM".

I am petty sure I know the cause as the links are getting opened on the same webpage, but I am doing a back navigation, which is not helping me at all.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are navigating back a page with `.navigate().back()`. After that initial click the page is changing, therefore you'll have to refind all the `a` elements again.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to program execution advancing to the call to "driver.navigate().back();" before the page has loaded.

Try introducing an [implicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits), which tells the "WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available"

e.g. When you create your web driver try:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I actually put the Thread.sleep for more than 5000 before and after driver navigation, but still the same thing.   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

Comment: @Edin_CA could you also include the target HTML in your question too?

Comment: OK. I will edit a little more: Login link, which happens to be the very first link works, as it opens in the same webpage. However, signup fails, as it opens up with a new url. That is why I had out the navigate.back thingy to prevent. Is there a way that I can continue executing my tests even when the pages open with a new url?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refind the element whenever a page is reloaded before you can interact with it, for your code, please try modify them to this:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    //clicking all links
    for (int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++){
        WebElement el = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i);            
        System.out.println("Link getting clicked"  + el.getText());
        el.click();
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
```